# How to make a list iteration with different actions depending on the value in Python

Tags: python, list, iteration

I have a list of languages. For example

```
languages = ['RU', ' EN', ' DE']
```

I need to make an itaration with different actions for each language.
I'm trying to do in the following way:

```
for x in languages:
    if x == 'EN':
        print(x, 'English')
    elif x == 'RU':
        print(x, 'Russian')
    elif x == 'DE':
        print(x, 'German')
    else:
        print('New Language')
```

But I have the result only for one of the languages.

```
RU Russian
New Language
New Language
New Language
New Language
```

How can I get the result for each language in a list?
Thank you

Comment: The strings in your list have spaces in them.

Comment: languages = ['RU', 'EN', 'DE'] Change your list

Comment: The if statement is trying to **exactly** match with the values. Some of the values in the array have spaces, so they don't match.

Comment: use strip() function to remove extra space from the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because a space is considered as a character. Remove that space or use the `strip` method on a string.

```
languages = ['RU', 'EN', 'DE']
```

```
if x.strip() == 'EN':
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some extra space in your languages list, just remove it and check.

```
languages = ['RU', 'EN', 'DE']
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a close look at the your list abbreviations apart from 'RU' have whitespace, use strip method to get rid of whitespace before comparsion

```
languages = ['RU', ' EN', ' DE']

for x in languages:
    x=x.strip()
    if x == 'EN':
        print(x, 'English')
    elif x == 'RU':
        print(x, 'Russian')
    elif x == 'DE':
        print(x, 'German')
    else:
        print('New Language')
```